# How duplicates removal is implemented in Set (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I am wondering how `Set` in ES6 is implemented under the hood. For example, if we do `new Set(arr)` and there are duplicates in `arr`, how `Set` removes them?

Comment: it just does not insert them

Answer (score 0):

It is done by checking the value equality ( `===` ) for every value in the set. If a duplicate value is found it isn't stored in the set.

For more info- [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)